# How to edit button form in position beside the inherited button

Tags: xml, odoo, v8

i want to position my button beside the inherited button  this is my code xml but isnt work i get button under to other

```
 <record id="holidays_views_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
        <field name="name">hr.holidays.form</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.holidays</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_holidays.edit_holiday_new"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <data>
                <header>
                   <xpath expr="//button[@name='refuse']" position="beside">
                    <button string="Retour" name="trainee_canceled_action" states="validate,validate1" type="object" groups=""  />
                  </xpath>
                </header>
```

[image]

Comment: Odoo dont knows "beside" like position value, you can try one of the followings:
**inside, after, before, replace, attributes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position attribute in Odoo has five options : `after`, `before`, `replace`, `inside` and `attributes` :

You can try below code:

```
 <record id="holidays_views_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">hr.holidays.form</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.holidays</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_holidays.edit_holiday_new"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <data>
            <header>
               <xpath expr="//button[@name='refuse']" position="after">
                <button string="Retour" name="trainee_canceled_action" states="validate,validate1" type="object" groups=""  />
              </xpath>
            </header>
```

Bests